# program keeps throwing an ArrayIndexOutofBoundException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

This code keeps throwing an `ArrayOutBoundsException 40` whenever the location gets to a certain point. Sometimes the program runs fine.

```
//method to get player movement around the board

public static void playerTurn(BoardSquare[] pos)
         {

          //variables to hold data
          int newLoc;
          int newBal;
          int newRoll;


         //instance of player
         Player player1 = new Player();

        //initialize
        newBal = player1.getBalance();
        newLoc = player1.getLocation();
        BoardSquare newPos;


       do{ 

        //user press a key to start the game
        System.out.println("Press enter");
        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        //player new roll, location, and balance
        newRoll = roll(); //roll of the dice
        newLoc = newLoc + (newRoll - 1); //player position
        newPos = pos[newLoc]; //info about location
        newBal = newBal - newPos.getRent(); //player new balance

        //necessary to keep the game going until player balace is 0
        if(newLoc > pos.length-1)
        {
          newLoc = (pos.length-1) - newLoc;//player new loc if > 39
        }
          //prints info on screen
          System.out.println(newRoll() + " " + newLoc + " " + newBal);   


       }while (newBal > 0);//loop until player balance get to zero


       }//ends method PlayerTurn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are doing the safety checks AFTER accessing the array, making them worthless. To fix this, you need to move the if statement from the end of the loop to in between `newLoc = newLoc + (newRoll - 1)` and `newPos = pos[newLoc]`. The guarantees that newLoc is less than the length of the array before accessing the array. As follows,

```
   do{ 

    //user press a key to start the game
    System.out.println("Press enter");
    new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

    //player new roll, location, and balance
    newRoll = roll(); //roll of the dice
    newLoc = newLoc + (newRoll - 1); //player position

    //necessary to keep the game going until player balace is 0
    if(newLoc > pos.length-1)
    {
      newLoc = (pos.length-1) - newLoc;//player new loc if > 39
    }

    newPos = pos[newLoc]; //info about location
    newBal = newBal - newPos.getRent(); //player new balance

    //prints info on screen
    System.out.println(newRoll() + " " + newLoc + " " + newBal);   


   }while (newBal > 0);//loop until player balance get to zero
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the line in error is:

```
newPos = pos[newLoc]; //info about location
```

it is possible that you are exceeding the array size of pos when newLoc is set to newLoc + roll.  This would cause an ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

Hope this helps!